# Why are my CSS grid starts and spans not working?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to arrange some playing cards in a clock shape, using a grid and grid positioning.

So far I have created 13 divs with id #1, #2, #3, etc. Each grid contains 4 nested images of playing cards, e.g.

```
<div id='clock'>
          <div id='1'>
            <img class='card1' src={cards.cAC} />
            <img class='card2' src={cards.cAH} />
            <img class='card3' src={cards.cAS} />
            <img class='card4' src={cards.cAD} />
          </div>
          <div id='2'>
            <img class='card1' src={cards.c2C} />
            <img class='card2' src={cards.c2H} />
            <img class='card3' src={cards.c2S} />
            <img class='card4' src={cards.c2D} />
          </div>
```

And so on, to 13 divs in total.

I created my css grid and two sample positions for divs #1 and #2 for starters:

```
#clock {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(27, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(17, 60px);
}

#1 {
  grid-column: 13 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

#2 {
  grid-column: 18 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
}
```

But the divs are still just auto-filling the grid with span 1 in each case as below - what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Edit: here's the grid I am trying to recreate:

[image]

Comment: The expected result is not clear. Why 27 columns and 17 rows, can you give more details?

Comment: No particular logic, I just made a grid in Excel where I laid out my "clock" to visualise it - and in the end the grid I was happy with was 27 x 17, with each div having a span of 3 x 3.  So for example, I want div #1 (the aces) to be positioned on row 1, 13 columns in.

Comment: Please share the visual grid that you made, so that could give some clarity.

Comment: I've added that at the bottom of the post now :)

Comment: CSS doesn't like Id's that start with a digit

Comment: @JonP arggggh that works thank you!